# Error when using backbone.js router

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Here is my code:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Everything related to routers....
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="../underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "foo/:bar" : "paramtest",
            "*action" : "func"
        },
        func: function (action) {
            console.log(action);
        },
        paramtest:function (p) {
            console.log(p);
        }
      });

      new Router();
      Backbone.history.start();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on' backbone-min.js:1
h.extend.start backbone-min.js:1
(anonymous function)

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery :0

Answer (score 3):

The current Backbone contains [this inside `Backbone.history.start`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-172):

```
if (this._hasPushState) {
  Backbone.$(window).on('popstate', this.checkUrl);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange && ('onhashchange' in window) && !oldIE) {
  Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange) {
  this._checkUrlInterval = setInterval(this.checkUrl, this.interval);
}
```

Note the `$(window).on()` calls (`Backbone.$` is just a namespaced reference to the usual `jQuery` function), that's where the error is coming from. You're using jQuery 1.4.4 but the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) wasn't added to jQuery until version 1.7.

You have two options:

1. Upgrade your jQuery to 1.7 or higher, preferably the latest jQuery.
2. Downgrade your Backbone to a version that doesn't use jQuery's `on`.

I don't know which version you'd use for option (2) but option (1) is a better idea anyway.